# Opening a local HTML page through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code where the **index.html** loads first. It has a text field and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, it calls the validateForm() function. Suppose the text field is empty, it should alert that it is empty, if it isn't then a new html page would load (either in new tab or current one) which is supposed to be **welcome.html**

So my problem is, the **welcome.html** file isn't loading. I even changed the "welcome.html" in `window.location.href = "welcome.html"` to "https://www.google.com" . The page still wouldn't load. What's wrong and what am I missing here ?

Any help is appreciated.

**index.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Form</title>
    
        <script src="/validateForm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**validateForm.js**

```js
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameData = name.value;

    if (nameData == "" || nameData == null) {
        alert("Name must be filled!");
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "welcome.html";
    }
}
```

**welcome.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome :)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure your code is executed? You could also check the debug console in you browser

Comment: @bwright couldn't find anything in the debug console. Tried executing with breakpoints. It looks like the browser refreshes or something similar to the effect you get when you click a href link . But after that effect it's still the same index.html page.

Comment: you are missing a   event.preventDefault() and I would add it to the click event of the submit butten, but oi think that is optional

Comment: @bwright but using `event.preventDefault` would render the return to **index.html** if the text field is empty not possible. I tried and it throws error 405.

Comment: try: https://jsfiddle.net/z1Lpak3g/

Comment: you do not cancel the form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `action` attribute

You can use the `action` attribute on the form to forward to a URL on success:

```html
<form method="get" action="welcome.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Documentation: [MDN - Form action attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action)

#### return value of `validateForm()`

See this?
`onsubmit="return validateForm()"`

Your `validateForm` doesn't return anything.
It is convention that `return false` means "stop processing the form" and a true-ish value means `continue`, which in turn means the `action` attribute mentioned above leads to `welcome.html` as you wanted.

The modified function could be this:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameData = name.value;

    if (nameData == "" || nameData == null) {
        alert("Name must be filled!");
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, give `validateForm` a first parameter named `event` and call `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false.

Documentation: [MDN - Form submit handling example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event#examples)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, looks like I still have a lot to look into on HTML and it's Documentation. I started learning HTML just yesterday.

Comment: Okay that's cool. There is a lot to learn, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

**You need some changes in `index.html` file and `validateForm.js` file**

index.html

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="return validate()" action="javascript::window.location.replace('welcome.html')">
...
</form>
```

and in `validateForm.js`
you need to return `true` or `false`
after validation function if `true` it redirects to `welcome.html` or if `false` nothing were heppened.

Comment: Although this answer is also correct, I don't think it adds anything that the accepted answer didn't already contain.